# Expanding Eucalyptus Faststart installation

Tags: cloud, eucalyptus

I have installed Eucalyptus using the Faststart method, but now I would like to expand it with three computer nodes.
Is that possible or do I need to install everything manually? This is for a private home cloud environment.

Also, can I use my NAS as an ISO and VM storage for all the nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding a Faststart installation is not supported and I've never seen anyone here or at the google group get help trying to do so.  That said, I've gotten a lot of great help here getting manual installations off the ground.  I have two tips to offer on how to proceed based on where you're at:

1. When going from Faststart to a more complex manual deploy, do a Faststart install with all of the network and naming details you anticipate using in the manual deploy and then read through the install log noted at the end of a successful installation.  It is very verbose, but in it you will find the exact commands you'd need to do a manual installation.  You can use them as a dummy check/crib sheet for planning your manual installation.
2. Start by reading through the beginning of the "[Installation Guide](https://docs.eucalyptus.cloud/eucalyptus/4.4.5/index.html#shared/install_section.html)" at least through the "[Plan Your Installation](https://docs.eucalyptus.cloud/eucalyptus/4.4.5/index.html#install-guide/planning.html)" section to see if Eucalpytus is going to fit your needs.  It answers most questions about architecture and where your VM and image stores can be configured.